# How to suppress prompt and supply an input therafter

Tags: c

I am not sure how to phrase this. But I have a C Program that will call another C Program in unix. After the call, the program(foo-exe) will prompt for an input "Y/N". I would like to suppress(hide) this prompting message and enter 'Y' thereafter as input. How do I go about doing that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    system("/home/xyz/foo-exe bar");
}
```

foo-exe

```
// do some other stuff
char ans = 'n';
printf("prompt message. Yes or no? (Y/N) ");
ans=getchar();
if(ans == 'Y') system("foo");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all (Y or N) the `foo-exe` expects then you could redirect its stdin to read from a pipe.

```
system("echo Y | /home/xyz/foo-exe bar");
```

But be aware of the [pitfalls](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132) of `system()` and its use is generally discouraged.

Comment: This did not work. Not sure if it matters but foo-exe does not immediately prompts for an input. It does do some other stuff before that. I have updated my question to reflect the snippet of how it prompts for the input

Comment: `foo-exe` doing other things doesn't matter. But if `foo-exe` is expecting multiple inputs then cause problems. You can run `foo-exe` it on the commandline to check that.

Comment: Running `/home/xyz/foo-exe bar` directly on terminal is fine. It gets to the point where it prompts for `Y/N`.

Comment: And running `echo Y | /home/xyz/foo-exe bar` on the terminal?

Comment: The prompt still comes out with nothing entered automatically. This comes out at my terminal(after I manually typed in 'y'). `prompt message. Yes or no? (Y/N) myusername@ubuntu32:~$ y
y: command not found`

Comment: That's odd. If foo-exe reads from stdin then `echo Y | ..` should work. May be, it expects multiple Y inputs? When you it directly on the terminal (without `echo Y`) did you wait until it comes back to the prompt and it expects only one Y?

Comment: Oh... it was a case sensitive issue. It expected an lower-case 'y'. But the prompt message is still not hidden though. I added the following to suppress it. `char output[1035];
 FILE *fp;
 fp = popen("echo y | /home/xyz/foo-exe bar", "r");
 fgets(output, sizeof(output)-1, fp);
 printf(output);`

Comment: Ok. `system("echo y | /home/xyz/foo-exe bar >/dev/null 2>&1");`  will hide the prompt as well (which redirects stdout and stderr to /dev/null).